# Quartz job failed to start

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz job that simply failed to start. Normally there is a log entry "your job -- FIRED!" and then "your job -- execution complete!".

The job is fairly simple. It is a Java method that wraps a call to an oracle stored procedure, and basically ends when that procedure ends. It normally takes 10-20 minutes to run completely and runs 3 times per month.

There is another very similar job that runs 30 minutes after this one, call it job2. Job2 started and completed just fine. There are no errors or stacktraces. There are settings that can turn all jobs off, but since job2 ran, there is no reason job1 should have been skipped.

I am using Quartz 1.5.

Where should I start trying to solve this problem?